# How do I make a pixel circle without any specifics other than wanting to use a multiple of a certain number?

Tags: algorithm, image, geometry, 2d, pixel

I’m trying to make a pixel art circle in Minecraft, but want to use a multiple of 64 blocks/pixels in the circle. I don’t want the corners to be connected, and I can’t figure out how to do the math. I’ve already looked at a different question on this site about making pixel circles, but it was talking about using a specific *number* of pixels, not a specific *multiple of a certain number* of pixels. Can someone please help me out?

Here is a sample of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Um, so try 64. If that doesn't work, try 128. If that doesn't work, try 192, etc.

Comment: @RaymondChen I have already tried to use a multiple of 64 as the area the circle is in. The math doesn’t work out to let it use a multiple of 64 pixels in the actual circle. There has got to be some kind of mathematical formula or something that can make the number of pixels used into a multiple of 64.

Comment: Maybe it's simply not possible. The center pixel makes the total odd. Or maybe you can adapt the other answer (which you haven't linked to). So far, this sounds like a mathematics problem, not a computer programming problem.

Comment: To clarify, is it that you want to draw a circle whose area is exactly equal to n*64 pixels, where n is an integer? If that's so, I really don't get the "I don’t want the corners to be connected" part. Can you explain?

Comment: @saastn I meant that the number of pixels used is n*64. The “I don’t want the corners to be connected” part is that each time the line making the circle moves inwards by one pixel, I only want it to connect to the previous line in the diagonal direction.

Comment: Are you drawing the outline of a circle? Or a filled-in circle? It sounds like you want the outline of a circle. And it sounds like you're drawing multiple circles concentric circle outlines, not just one circle?

Comment: I just got more confused. Could you please edit your question and add a picture to show what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I’m trying to make an outline of a circle, and I will edit my question to add a picture.

Comment: In your picture, some of the pixels are connected corner-to-corner, which you said you didn't want: "I don’t want the corners to be connected."

Comment: @RaymondChen I meant the sides not the corners, my bad

Comment: But there are also pixels connected side-to-side.

Comment: @RaymondChen But those are to make it more circular; I just don’t want the sides connected when it goes to a new section of the circle. Does that make sense now?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now with the example you gave we know what we are talking about. First of all, we must know that there is no such thing as a circle in the raster space. The only things that exist are collections of pixels that one may or may not consider to be circles.

If we accept such an assumption, then math cannot help much. What we need is an algorithm to generate various circle-like shapes and check whether each of them satisfies the desired condition or not.

I used a brute force search algorithm to generate such shapes. There are three variables that need to be set: radius, thickness, and whether the origin is in the middle of the pixel or at its corner (e.g. 50 or 50.5). Now we find the distance of all the pixels of the image from the origin and select the pixels whose distance from the radius is less than half the thickness. Then we count the number of selected pixels and if it is a multiple of 64, we add the shape to the results. Note that there is a possibility of producing duplicated shapes.

These are the results of running the algorithm:

[image]

```
   center     radius    thick.   num. px.
   50.0000    4.0000    2.2000   64.0000
   50.0000    4.5000    2.4000   64.0000
   50.0000    4.8000    2.1000   64.0000
   50.0000    5.2000    2.0000   64.0000
   50.0000    5.9000    1.7000   64.0000
   50.0000    6.3000    1.6000   64.0000
   50.0000    6.7000    1.3000   64.0000
   50.0000    6.9000    1.5000   64.0000
   50.0000    7.1000    1.5000   64.0000
   50.0000    7.6000    1.1000   64.0000
   50.0000    7.8000    1.4000   64.0000
   50.0000    7.9000    1.3000   64.0000
   50.0000    8.0000    1.3000   64.0000
   50.0000    8.2000    2.3000  128.0000
   50.0000    8.3000    1.3000   64.0000
   50.0000    8.6000    1.1000   64.0000
   50.0000    8.7000    1.1000   64.0000
   50.0000    8.7000    2.4000  128.0000
   50.0000    8.9000    1.1000   64.0000
   50.0000    9.1000    2.1000  128.0000
   50.0000    9.2000    2.2000  128.0000
   50.0000    9.3000    1.2000   64.0000
   50.0000    9.4000    2.1000  128.0000
   50.0000    9.6000    0.9000   64.0000
   50.0000    9.8000    1.0000   64.0000
   50.0000   10.0000    1.1000   64.0000
   50.0000   10.1000    1.1000   64.0000
   50.0000   10.3000    2.1000  128.0000
   50.0000   10.5000    1.9000  128.0000
   50.0000   10.9000    1.0000   64.0000
   50.0000   11.1000    0.7000   64.0000
   50.0000   11.3000    0.9000   64.0000
   50.0000   11.7000    0.8000   64.0000
   50.0000   12.3000    2.4000  192.0000
   50.0000   12.5000    2.4000  192.0000
   50.0000   12.7000    0.7000   64.0000
   50.0000   12.8000    0.8000   64.0000
   50.0000   12.8000    2.4000  192.0000
   50.0000   12.9000    1.5000  128.0000
   50.0000   12.9000    2.4000  192.0000
   50.0000   13.0000    0.8000   64.0000
   50.0000   13.1000    1.7000  128.0000
   50.0000   13.1000    2.2000  192.0000
   50.0000   13.4000    0.8000   64.0000
   50.0000   13.4000    1.5000  128.0000
   50.0000   13.5000    0.9000   64.0000
   50.0000   13.5000    2.3000  192.0000
   50.0000   13.6000    2.4000  192.0000
   50.0000   13.7000    1.4000  128.0000
   50.0000   13.8000    0.7000   64.0000
   50.0000   13.8000    2.2000  192.0000
   50.0000   13.9000    0.7000   64.0000
   50.0000   13.9000    1.5000  128.0000
   50.0000   14.0000    0.7000   64.0000
   50.0000   14.0000    1.6000  128.0000
   50.0000   14.2000    1.5000  128.0000
   50.0000   14.3000    0.7000   64.0000
   50.0000   14.6000    2.1000  192.0000
   50.0000   14.7000    1.2000  128.0000
   50.0000   14.9000    1.4000  128.0000
   50.0000   14.9000    2.0000  192.0000
   50.0000   15.2000    1.3000  128.0000
   50.0000   15.7000    1.2000  128.0000
   50.0000   15.8000    1.3000  128.0000
   50.0000   15.9000    1.3000  128.0000
   50.0000   16.0000    1.3000  128.0000
   50.0000   16.1000    1.9000  192.0000
   50.0000   16.2000    1.3000  128.0000
   50.0000   16.3000    1.9000  192.0000
   50.0000   16.3000    2.4000  256.0000
   50.0000   16.5000    0.7000   64.0000
   50.0000   16.5000    1.9000  192.0000
   50.0000   16.5000    2.5000  256.0000
   50.0000   16.6000    1.1000  128.0000
   50.0000   16.7000    2.4000  256.0000
   50.0000   16.8000    1.3000  128.0000
   50.0000   16.9000    1.2000  128.0000
   50.0000   16.9000    2.3000  256.0000
   50.0000   17.1000    2.3000  256.0000
   50.0000   17.3000    1.2000  128.0000
   50.0000   17.4000    2.3000  256.0000
   50.0000   17.5000    0.7000   64.0000
   50.0000   17.5000    2.4000  256.0000
   50.0000   17.6000    0.7000   64.0000
   50.0000   17.7000    2.4000  256.0000
   50.0000   18.0000    1.8000  192.0000
   50.0000   18.1000    1.2000  128.0000
   50.0000   18.7000    2.2000  256.0000
   50.0000   18.8000    0.9000  128.0000
   50.0000   18.8000    1.6000  192.0000
   50.0000   18.8000    2.2000  256.0000
   50.0000   18.9000    1.7000  192.0000
   50.0000   18.9000    2.2000  256.0000
   50.0000   19.3000    1.9000  256.0000
   50.0000   19.7000    1.0000  128.0000
   50.0000   19.8000    1.0000  128.0000
   50.0000   19.9000    1.0000  128.0000
   50.0000   20.1000    1.0000  128.0000
   50.0000   20.1000    1.6000  192.0000
   50.0000   20.2000    0.9000  128.0000
   50.0000   20.3000    2.0000  256.0000
   50.0000   20.3000    2.4000  320.0000
   50.0000   20.4000    2.0000  256.0000
   50.0000   20.4000    2.4000  320.0000
   50.0000   20.5000    2.0000  256.0000
   50.0000   20.6000    0.7000   64.0000
   50.0000   20.6000    1.9000  256.0000
   50.0000   20.7000    1.9000  256.0000
   50.0000   20.8000    1.0000  128.0000
   50.0000   20.9000    1.0000  128.0000
   50.0000   20.9000    1.4000  192.0000
   50.0000   21.0000    0.9000  128.0000
   50.0000   21.0000    2.0000  256.0000
   50.0000   21.0000    2.4000  320.0000
   50.0000   21.1000    2.3000  320.0000
   50.0000   21.2000    0.9000  128.0000
   50.0000   21.2000    1.5000  192.0000
   50.0000   21.6000    0.9000  128.0000
   50.0000   21.7000    1.9000  256.0000
   50.0000   21.8000    1.4000  192.0000
   50.0000   21.8000    1.9000  256.0000
   50.0000   21.9000    1.4000  192.0000
   50.0000   22.0000    1.5000  192.0000
   50.0000   22.1000    2.2000  320.0000
   50.0000   22.2000    0.9000  128.0000
   50.0000   22.2000    1.4000  192.0000
   50.0000   22.3000    0.8000  128.0000
   50.0000   22.7000    1.3000  192.0000
   50.0000   22.8000    0.9000  128.0000
   50.0000   22.8000    1.3000  192.0000
   50.0000   22.8000    2.4000  320.0000
   50.0000   23.0000    1.3000  192.0000
   50.0000   23.0000    1.9000  256.0000
   50.0000   23.2000    1.4000  192.0000
   50.0000   23.2000    2.2000  320.0000
   50.0000   23.4000    0.8000  128.0000
   50.0000   23.4000    2.1000  320.0000
   50.0000   23.5000    2.2000  320.0000
   50.0000   23.6000    0.9000  128.0000
   50.0000   23.6000    2.2000  320.0000
   50.0000   23.7000    0.8000  128.0000
   50.0000   23.8000    0.8000  128.0000
   50.0000   23.9000    0.9000  128.0000
   50.0000   23.9000    1.7000  256.0000
   50.0000   23.9000    2.5000  384.0000
   50.0000   24.0000    0.8000  128.0000
   50.0000   24.0000    1.7000  256.0000
   50.0000   24.0000    2.1000  320.0000
   50.0000   24.0000    2.4000  384.0000
   50.0000   24.1000    0.8000  128.0000
   50.0000   24.2000    1.3000  192.0000
   50.0000   24.3000    0.8000  128.0000
   50.0000   24.3000    2.5000  384.0000
   50.0000   24.5000    0.9000  128.0000
   50.0000   24.7000    2.0000  320.0000
   50.0000   24.9000    1.2000  192.0000
   50.0000   24.9000    2.1000  320.0000
   50.0000   25.1000    1.2000  192.0000
   50.0000   25.2000    0.8000  128.0000
   50.0000   25.7000    0.8000  128.0000
   50.0000   25.8000    2.3000  384.0000
   50.0000   26.0000    1.1000  192.0000
   50.0000   26.0000    1.7000  256.0000
   50.0000   26.1000    2.0000  320.0000
   50.0000   26.2000    2.0000  320.0000
   50.0000   26.3000    2.4000  384.0000
   50.0000   26.4000    1.1000  192.0000
   50.0000   26.6000    0.8000  128.0000
   50.0000   26.7000    1.1000  192.0000
   50.0000   26.8000    1.5000  256.0000
   50.0000   26.9000    2.3000  384.0000
   50.0000   27.0000    0.7000  128.0000
   50.0000   27.0000    1.9000  320.0000
   50.0000   27.0000    2.2000  384.0000
   50.0000   27.1000    1.2000  192.0000
   50.0000   27.3000    1.1000  192.0000
   50.0000   27.4000    2.2000  384.0000
   50.0000   27.6000    1.8000  320.0000
   50.0000   27.6000    2.3000  384.0000
   50.0000   27.8000    1.5000  256.0000
   50.0000   27.8000    2.3000  384.0000
   50.0000   27.9000    1.1000  192.0000
   50.0000   28.0000    1.5000  256.0000
   50.0000   28.2000    0.7000  128.0000
   50.0000   28.2000    1.5000  256.0000
   50.0000   28.2000    2.5000  448.0000
   50.0000   28.3000    1.1000  192.0000
   50.0000   28.5000    2.5000  448.0000
   50.0000   28.6000    0.8000  128.0000
   50.0000   28.7000    1.0000  192.0000
   50.0000   28.7000    1.4000  256.0000
   50.0000   28.8000    1.3000  256.0000
   50.0000   28.8000    1.8000  320.0000
   50.0000   28.8000    2.1000  384.0000
   50.0000   29.1000    1.8000  320.0000
   50.0000   29.1000    2.0000  384.0000
   50.0000   29.4000    1.1000  192.0000
   50.0000   29.4000    2.4000  448.0000
   50.0000   29.6000    0.8000  128.0000
   50.0000   29.7000    0.7000  128.0000
   50.0000   29.8000    1.6000  320.0000
   50.0000   29.9000    0.7000  128.0000
   50.0000   29.9000    1.4000  256.0000
   50.0000   29.9000    2.4000  448.0000
   50.0000   30.0000    0.7000  128.0000
   50.0000   30.0000    1.4000  256.0000
   50.0000   30.4000    0.7000  128.0000
   50.0000   30.4000    1.7000  320.0000
   50.0000   30.5000    2.5000  448.0000
   50.0000   30.6000    2.0000  384.0000
   50.0000   30.7000    1.0000  192.0000
   50.0000   30.7000    1.3000  256.0000
   50.0000   30.8000    1.0000  192.0000
   50.0000   30.8000    1.3000  256.0000
   50.0000   30.9000    0.7000  128.0000
   50.0000   30.9000    2.3000  448.0000
   50.0000   31.0000    1.0000  192.0000
   50.0000   31.0000    2.0000  384.0000
   50.0000   31.0000    2.3000  448.0000
   50.0000   31.1000    1.7000  320.0000
   50.0000   31.2000    1.1000  192.0000
   50.0000   31.2000    1.4000  256.0000
   50.0000   31.2000    2.5000  512.0000
   50.0000   31.4000    1.0000  192.0000
   50.0000   31.5000    2.2000  448.0000
   50.0000   31.6000    0.7000  128.0000
   50.0000   31.6000    2.3000  448.0000
   50.0000   31.7000    2.3000  448.0000
   50.0000   31.8000    1.9000  384.0000
   50.0000   32.0000    1.1000  192.0000
   50.0000   32.0000    1.6000  320.0000
   50.0000   32.1000    1.6000  320.0000
   50.0000   32.2000    2.4000  512.0000
   50.0000   32.4000    0.9000  192.0000
   50.0000   32.6000    1.0000  192.0000
   50.0000   32.7000    0.7000  128.0000
   50.0000   32.7000    1.2000  256.0000
   50.0000   32.8000    0.9000  192.0000
   50.0000   32.8000    2.3000  448.0000
   50.0000   32.9000    0.9000  192.0000
   50.0000   32.9000    1.5000  320.0000
   50.0000   33.1000    1.2000  256.0000
   50.0000   33.2000    1.6000  320.0000
   50.0000   33.4000    2.4000  512.0000
   50.0000   33.5000    2.1000  448.0000
   50.0000   33.5000    2.5000  512.0000
   50.0000   33.6000    2.5000  512.0000
   50.0000   33.8000    1.2000  256.0000
   50.0000   34.0000    1.3000  256.0000
   50.0000   34.0000    1.8000  384.0000
   50.0000   34.0000    2.4000  512.0000
   50.0000   34.1000    0.9000  192.0000
   50.0000   34.1000    1.2000  256.0000
   50.0000   34.1000    1.6000  320.0000
   50.0000   34.1000    2.3000  512.0000
   50.0000   34.2000    1.2000  256.0000
   50.0000   34.4000    2.1000  448.0000
   50.0000   34.5000    0.9000  192.0000
   50.0000   34.5000    2.0000  448.0000
   50.0000   34.6000    0.7000  128.0000
   50.0000   34.6000    2.1000  448.0000
   50.0000   34.7000    1.4000  320.0000
   50.0000   34.9000    1.5000  320.0000
   50.0000   34.9000    2.0000  448.0000
   50.0000   35.0000    0.9000  192.0000
   50.0000   35.0000    1.1000  256.0000
   50.0000   35.0000    1.8000  384.0000
   50.0000   35.1000    0.8000  192.0000
   50.0000   35.1000    1.2000  256.0000
   50.0000   35.2000    1.2000  256.0000
   50.0000   35.2000    1.5000  320.0000
   50.0000   35.6000    1.1000  256.0000
   50.0000   35.9000    1.5000  320.0000
   50.0000   36.0000    1.4000  320.0000
   50.0000   36.1000    2.0000  448.0000
   50.0000   36.4000    2.2000  512.0000
   50.0000   36.4000    2.5000  576.0000
   50.0000   36.5000    2.5000  576.0000
   50.0000   36.6000    0.9000  192.0000
   50.0000   36.6000    2.5000  576.0000
   50.0000   36.7000    0.9000  192.0000
   50.0000   36.7000    1.1000  256.0000
   50.0000   36.9000    1.6000  384.0000
   50.0000   37.0000    1.9000  448.0000
   50.0000   37.1000    0.8000  192.0000
   50.0000   37.1000    1.4000  320.0000
   50.0000   37.2000    1.5000  320.0000
   50.0000   37.2000    2.3000  576.0000
   50.0000   37.3000    1.1000  256.0000
   50.0000   37.3000    2.4000  576.0000
   50.0000   37.4000    1.6000  384.0000
   50.0000   37.4000    1.9000  448.0000
   50.0000   37.5000    1.1000  256.0000
   50.0000   37.5000    1.3000  320.0000
   50.0000   37.5000    1.9000  448.0000
   50.0000   37.5000    2.2000  512.0000
   50.0000   37.6000    2.1000  512.0000
   50.0000   37.7000    1.1000  256.0000
   50.0000   37.7000    2.5000  576.0000
   50.0000   37.8000    1.6000  384.0000
   50.0000   37.8000    2.2000  512.0000
   50.0000   37.9000    1.1000  256.0000
   50.0000   38.0000    0.8000  192.0000
   50.0000   38.0000    1.3000  320.0000
   50.0000   38.0000    1.7000  384.0000
   50.0000   38.1000    0.8000  192.0000
   50.0000   38.1000    2.4000  576.0000
   50.0000   38.2000    0.8000  192.0000
   50.0000   38.2000    1.4000  320.0000
   50.0000   38.4000    2.4000  576.0000
   50.0000   38.6000    2.1000  512.0000
   50.0000   38.7000    2.2000  512.0000
   50.0000   38.7000    2.4000  576.0000
   50.0000   38.8000    1.3000  320.0000
   50.0000   38.8000    2.1000  512.0000
   50.0000   38.9000    1.8000  448.0000
   50.0000   38.9000    2.1000  512.0000
   50.0000   39.1000    1.4000  320.0000
   50.0000   39.2000    2.1000  512.0000
   50.0000   39.3000    2.5000  640.0000
   50.0000   39.4000    0.8000  192.0000
   50.0000   39.4000    1.0000  256.0000
   50.0000   39.7000    0.8000  192.0000
   50.0000   39.8000    0.8000  192.0000
   50.0000   39.8000    1.3000  320.0000
   50.0000   39.9000    0.8000  192.0000
   50.0000   39.9000    1.0000  256.0000
   50.0000   39.9000    1.6000  384.0000
   50.5000    3.7000    2.5000   64.0000
   50.5000    3.9000    2.5000   64.0000
   50.5000    4.3000    2.5000   64.0000
   50.5000    5.4000    2.0000   64.0000
   50.5000    5.7000    1.7000   64.0000
   50.5000    7.1000    1.2000   64.0000
   50.5000    7.5000    2.5000  128.0000
   50.5000    8.1000    2.5000  128.0000
   50.5000    8.3000    2.5000  128.0000
   50.5000    8.4000    1.0000   64.0000
   50.5000    8.6000    2.2000  128.0000
   50.5000    8.7000    2.3000  128.0000
   50.5000    8.8000    2.3000  128.0000
   50.5000    9.6000    2.1000  128.0000
   50.5000    9.7000    0.9000   64.0000
   50.5000    9.7000    2.1000  128.0000
   50.5000    9.8000    2.0000  128.0000
   50.5000   10.0000    2.0000  128.0000
   50.5000   10.1000    1.0000   64.0000
   50.5000   11.1000    0.9000   64.0000
   50.5000   11.1000    1.9000  128.0000
   50.5000   11.2000    0.9000   64.0000
   50.5000   11.3000    1.0000   64.0000
   50.5000   11.5000    0.9000   64.0000
   50.5000   11.5000    2.5000  192.0000
   50.5000   11.8000    2.4000  192.0000
   50.5000   12.3000    2.5000  192.0000
   50.5000   12.4000    0.7000   64.0000
   50.5000   12.4000    2.4000  192.0000
   50.5000   12.6000    0.7000   64.0000
   50.5000   12.6000    1.7000  128.0000
   50.5000   12.8000    0.9000   64.0000
   50.5000   12.8000    2.5000  192.0000
   50.5000   12.9000    2.4000  192.0000
   50.5000   13.0000    2.4000  192.0000
   50.5000   13.1000    2.3000  192.0000
   50.5000   13.8000    0.7000   64.0000
   50.5000   13.8000    2.2000  192.0000
   50.5000   13.9000    0.7000   64.0000
   50.5000   13.9000    2.2000  192.0000
   50.5000   14.0000    0.7000   64.0000
   50.5000   14.1000    1.3000  128.0000
   50.5000   14.1000    2.2000  192.0000
   50.5000   14.3000    0.7000   64.0000
   50.5000   15.2000    0.7000   64.0000
   50.5000   15.3000    0.7000   64.0000
   50.5000   15.4000    1.9000  192.0000
   50.5000   15.5000    0.7000   64.0000
   50.5000   15.5000    1.3000  128.0000
   50.5000   15.5000    1.9000  192.0000
   50.5000   15.6000    2.0000  192.0000
   50.5000   15.7000    2.4000  256.0000
   50.5000   15.8000    2.0000  192.0000
   50.5000   15.8000    2.5000  256.0000
   50.5000   15.9000    0.7000   64.0000
   50.5000   16.5000    2.4000  256.0000
   50.5000   16.7000    2.3000  256.0000
   50.5000   16.9000    1.2000  128.0000
   50.5000   16.9000    1.7000  192.0000
   50.5000   16.9000    2.4000  256.0000
   50.5000   17.0000    1.2000  128.0000
   50.5000   17.0000    1.7000  192.0000
   50.5000   17.0000    2.4000  256.0000
   50.5000   17.2000    0.7000   64.0000
   50.5000   17.2000    2.5000  256.0000
   50.5000   17.3000    0.7000   64.0000
   50.5000   17.4000    2.3000  256.0000
   50.5000   18.1000    2.3000  256.0000
   50.5000   18.2000    0.7000   64.0000
   50.5000   18.4000    1.5000  192.0000
   50.5000   18.4000    2.3000  256.0000
   50.5000   18.5000    1.1000  128.0000
   50.5000   18.5000    2.2000  256.0000
   50.5000   18.6000    2.1000  256.0000
   50.5000   18.7000    2.1000  256.0000
   50.5000   19.5000    2.1000  256.0000
   50.5000   19.6000    2.5000  320.0000
   50.5000   19.7000    1.7000  192.0000
   50.5000   19.7000    2.4000  320.0000
   50.5000   19.8000    1.0000  128.0000
   50.5000   19.8000    2.0000  256.0000
   50.5000   19.8000    2.5000  320.0000
   50.5000   19.9000    1.1000  128.0000
   50.5000   19.9000    2.0000  256.0000
   50.5000   20.8000    2.4000  320.0000
   50.5000   21.1000    1.0000  128.0000
   50.5000   21.1000    2.0000  256.0000
   50.5000   21.1000    2.4000  320.0000
   50.5000   21.2000    1.3000  192.0000
   50.5000   21.3000    1.0000  128.0000
   50.5000   21.3000    2.5000  320.0000
   50.5000   21.4000    1.0000  128.0000
   50.5000   21.4000    1.8000  256.0000
   50.5000   21.4000    2.4000  320.0000
   50.5000   21.6000    2.2000  320.0000
   50.5000   22.3000    2.3000  320.0000
   50.5000   22.5000    1.9000  256.0000
   50.5000   22.5000    2.1000  320.0000
   50.5000   22.6000    0.9000  128.0000
   50.5000   22.6000    1.5000  192.0000
   50.5000   22.7000    1.8000  256.0000
   50.5000   22.7000    2.2000  320.0000
   50.5000   22.8000    0.8000  128.0000
   50.5000   22.8000    1.8000  256.0000
   50.5000   23.0000    2.2000  320.0000
   50.5000   23.8000    0.7000  128.0000
   50.5000   23.8000    2.5000  384.0000
   50.5000   23.9000    1.7000  256.0000
   50.5000   23.9000    2.1000  320.0000
   50.5000   24.0000    1.2000  192.0000
   50.5000   24.1000    1.6000  256.0000
   50.5000   24.1000    2.1000  320.0000
   50.5000   24.2000    0.9000  128.0000
   50.5000   24.3000    0.8000  128.0000
   50.5000   24.3000    2.1000  320.0000
   50.5000   24.3000    2.5000  384.0000
   50.5000   25.0000    2.5000  384.0000
   50.5000   25.1000    2.4000  384.0000
   50.5000   25.2000    2.1000  320.0000
   50.5000   25.2000    2.4000  384.0000
   50.5000   25.4000    0.7000  128.0000
   50.5000   25.4000    1.2000  192.0000
   50.5000   25.4000    2.0000  320.0000
   50.5000   25.5000    1.3000  192.0000
   50.5000   25.5000    1.6000  256.0000
   50.5000   25.5000    2.3000  384.0000
   50.5000   25.6000    2.0000  320.0000
   50.5000   26.6000    2.2000  384.0000
   50.5000   26.7000    2.3000  384.0000
   50.5000   26.8000    2.3000  384.0000
   50.5000   27.0000    0.8000  128.0000
   50.5000   27.0000    1.1000  192.0000
   50.5000   27.2000    2.3000  384.0000
   50.5000   27.3000    2.5000  448.0000
   50.5000   27.4000    2.5000  448.0000
   50.5000   27.8000    2.5000  448.0000
   50.5000   27.9000    2.2000  384.0000
   50.5000   28.0000    2.2000  384.0000
   50.5000   28.1000    1.8000  320.0000
   50.5000   28.1000    2.1000  384.0000
   50.5000   28.1000    2.5000  448.0000
   50.5000   28.3000    0.7000  128.0000
   50.5000   28.3000    1.6000  320.0000
   50.5000   28.3000    2.2000  384.0000
   50.5000   28.4000    1.1000  192.0000
   50.5000   28.4000    2.2000  384.0000
   50.5000   28.5000    0.7000  128.0000
   50.5000   28.6000    2.4000  448.0000
   50.5000   29.4000    0.7000  128.0000
   50.5000   29.6000    1.1000  192.0000
   50.5000   29.8000    1.0000  192.0000
   50.5000   29.8000    1.7000  320.0000
   50.5000   29.8000    1.9000  384.0000
   50.5000   29.8000    2.4000  448.0000
   50.5000   29.9000    0.7000  128.0000
   50.5000   29.9000    2.4000  448.0000
   50.5000   30.9000    2.3000  448.0000
   50.5000   31.1000    1.2000  256.0000
   50.5000   31.1000    1.6000  320.0000
   50.5000   31.1000    1.9000  384.0000
   50.5000   31.1000    2.4000  448.0000
   50.5000   31.2000    0.7000  128.0000
   50.5000   31.3000    1.9000  384.0000
   50.5000   31.3000    2.3000  448.0000
   50.5000   31.4000    2.3000  448.0000
   50.5000   31.4000    2.5000  512.0000
   50.5000   31.6000    2.5000  512.0000
   50.5000   32.3000    0.9000  192.0000
   50.5000   32.4000    1.9000  384.0000
   50.5000   32.4000    2.5000  512.0000
   50.5000   32.5000    1.9000  384.0000
   50.5000   32.5000    2.1000  448.0000
   50.5000   32.6000    1.0000  192.0000
   50.5000   32.6000    2.5000  512.0000
   50.5000   32.7000    0.9000  192.0000
   50.5000   32.7000    1.8000  384.0000
   50.5000   32.8000    2.2000  448.0000
   50.5000   33.0000    2.5000  512.0000
   50.5000   33.4000    2.5000  512.0000
   50.5000   33.7000    1.9000  384.0000
   50.5000   33.7000    2.3000  512.0000
   50.5000   34.0000    1.2000  256.0000
   50.5000   34.0000    1.7000  384.0000
   50.5000   34.1000    2.1000  448.0000
   50.5000   34.2000    2.0000  448.0000
   50.5000   35.0000    2.3000  512.0000
   50.5000   35.2000    1.1000  256.0000
   50.5000   35.2000    2.0000  448.0000
   50.5000   35.2000    2.4000  512.0000
   50.5000   35.3000    1.6000  384.0000
   50.5000   35.3000    2.0000  448.0000
   50.5000   35.3000    2.4000  512.0000
   50.5000   35.4000    0.8000  192.0000
   50.5000   35.4000    1.7000  384.0000
   50.5000   35.4000    2.1000  448.0000
   50.5000   35.6000    0.9000  192.0000
   50.5000   35.6000    2.2000  512.0000
   50.5000   36.3000    2.5000  576.0000
   50.5000   36.4000    2.5000  576.0000
   50.5000   36.6000    2.4000  576.0000
   50.5000   36.7000    1.7000  384.0000
   50.5000   36.8000    0.8000  192.0000
   50.5000   36.8000    2.5000  576.0000
   50.5000   36.9000    0.8000  192.0000
   50.5000   36.9000    1.9000  448.0000
   50.5000   37.0000    2.2000  512.0000
   50.5000   37.0000    2.5000  576.0000
   50.5000   37.1000    2.2000  512.0000
   50.5000   37.2000    2.5000  576.0000
   50.5000   37.8000    2.4000  576.0000
   50.5000   38.0000    1.9000  448.0000
   50.5000   38.1000    1.1000  256.0000
   50.5000   38.1000    1.8000  448.0000
   50.5000   38.2000    1.5000  384.0000
   50.5000   38.2000    1.8000  448.0000
   50.5000   38.3000    1.1000  256.0000
   50.5000   38.3000    2.5000  576.0000
   50.5000   38.4000    0.8000  192.0000
   50.5000   38.4000    2.4000  576.0000
   50.5000   38.5000    2.1000  512.0000
   50.5000   38.6000    2.3000  576.0000
   50.5000   39.4000    0.8000  192.0000
   50.5000   39.4000    1.0000  256.0000
   50.5000   39.4000    2.3000  576.0000
   50.5000   39.7000    0.8000  192.0000
   50.5000   39.7000    1.8000  448.0000
   50.5000   39.8000    0.7000  192.0000
   50.5000   39.8000    2.1000  512.0000
   50.5000   39.9000    2.3000  576.0000
   50.5000   39.9000    2.5000  640.0000
```

Comment: Thanks!! I will try that and hopefully it will be helpful!!